# How to change the font size of selected text in edittext at runtime?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textattributes

I am developing a text editor for my application, in which i want to edit the selected portion of text. And i am almost done with it except one feature, that to decrease the size of selected text.

I could increase the size like : 
`text=editor.getText();
text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editor.setText(text);`

But i am stuck with decreasing the size, How the size of text can be decreased ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set font style of selected text using custom typeface through spannable method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710300/how-to-set-font-style-of-selected-text-using-custom-typeface-through-spannable-m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the same way as you have used for increase textsize used code as shown below where editor is EditText

```
 Spannable text=(Spannable)editor.getText(); 
 text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.2f), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);    
 editor.setText(text);
```

in RelativeSizeSpan i have used **0.2f** as a text size which will decrese your textsize you can use what ever size you need accordinglly